# Comparing cube and cylinder with same lengths

Tags: geometry

> The side of a cube, the height of a cylinder, and the diameter of the cylinder each has length $s$.  What is the ratio of the volume of the cube to the volume of the cylinder?
>
> (a) $6:\pi$
>
> (b) $2:\pi$
>
> (c) $4:\pi$
>
> (d) $1:\pi$
>
> [volume of cube and volume of cylinder]

Comment: Looked in College Geometry and College Trigonometry textbooks for the answer but to no avail.  Hope someone has an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: When written out $\pi$ is pi, not pie and $\pi \neq 3.1416$.  The geometry text should have had the [volume of the cylinder](https://www.google.com/search?q=volume+of+a+cylinder&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS732US736&oq=volume+of+a+cylinder&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5304j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  The link I posted was the first one that came up.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a cube with side $s$ is $s^3$.

The area of a circle with diameter $s$ is $\pi (s/2)^2 = (\pi/4) s^2$.  The volume of a (right, circular) cylinder of diameter $s$ and height $s$ is the area of that circle times the height, $(\pi/4) s^2 \cdot s = (\pi/4) s^3$.

The ratio of the volume of the cube to that of the cylinder is \begin{align}
    s^3 : (\pi/4) s^3 &= 1 : \pi/4  \\
    &= 4 : \pi  \text{.}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  It makes sense.